# Can't locate object method "execute" via package "DBI::db"

Tags: perl, dbi

my code is the following:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;

    $self->initialize();

    return $self;
}

sub initialize
{
    my $self = shift;

    $self->connect();

    $self->{'dbh'}
        ->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'settings' (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Option TEXT, Value TEXT)");
}

sub connect
{
    my $self = shift;

    $self->{'dbh'} = DBI->connect($self->DSN, "", "", {
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1
    });

    die "Can't connect" unless($self->{'dbh'});
}

sub no_options
{
    my$self = shift;

    $self->{'dbh'}->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM settings");
    # Here is the problem i get the error here:
    # Can't locate object method "execute" via package "DBI::db"
    $self->{'dbh'}->execute();
    my %row = $self->{'dbh'}->fetchhash_array;

    return $row{'Total'};
}
```

in other place i call my package

```
my $test = Lib::PackageName->new;

print $test->no_options;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`prepare`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#prepare) method returns a statement object. It is this object that has the [`execute`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#execute) method.

```
my $statement = $self->{'dbh'}->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM settings");
$statement->execute();
```

There is no method named `fetchhash_array` in [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI). The available fetch methods for the statement object are:

- [`fetchrow_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref)
- [`fetchrow_array`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchrow_array)
- [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchrow_hashref)
- [`fetchall_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchall_arrayref)
- [`fetchall_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchall_hashref)

Comment: now i get `Can't locate object method "fetchhash_array" via package "DBI::st"`

Comment: There is no such method in `DBI`. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$self->{'dbh'}->prepare(...)` returns a statement handle which you should keep for further use:

```
my $sth = $self->{'dbh'}->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM settings");
$sth->execute;
my %row = $sth->fetchhash_array;
```